# Preventing destructor call after kernel call in CUDA

Tags: cuda, raii

Considere this simplified version of my problem: To pass data to a CUDA kernel, I use a class which holds data and a pointer to data on the graphics hardware.

```
class A {
  int data;
  float* dataOnGPU;
  A() { cudaMalloc( dataOnGPU ... ); }
  ~A() { cudaFree( dataOnGPU ... ); }
};

void myFunction()
{
  A obj;
  kernelCall1<<<1,1>>>( obj );
  kernelCall2<<<1,1>>>( obj ); // obj.dataOnGPU no longer points to valid memory

}
```

Returning form the first kernel call results in calling the destructor of the copy of obj (since the kernel is called by value, which creates a copy). This frees dataOnGPU for both obj and its copy. The memory of obj.dataOnGPU should not be free until obj goes out of scope.

Of course, there are possibilities to avoid this, but I'd like to have nice and clean RAII behavior. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom copy constructor was the solution:

```
class A {
  int data;
  float* dataOnGPU;
  bool isCopy;
  A() { cudaMalloc( dataOnGPU ... ); isCopy = false; }
  A( const A& _orig ) { *this = _orig; isCopy = true; }
  ~A() { if (!isCopy) cudaFree( dataOnGPU ... ); }
};

void myFunction()
{
  A obj;
  kernelCall1<<<1,1>>>( obj );
  kernelCall2<<<1,1>>>( obj ); // obj.dataOnGPU still points to valid memory
}
```

Thanks to Paul R for indirectly pointing me to this :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your destructor to:

```
~A() { cudaDeviceSynchronize(); cudaFree( dataOnGPU ... ); }
```

so that the kernel runs to completion before you free memory.

Comment: This will still free obj.dataOnGPU which should be available in the second kernel call.

Comment: OK - so you only have a shallow copy for your A class ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assumed that specifying no copy constructor indicates that a shallow copy is performed.

Comment: OK - I think your basic design is broken - why not just pass A to the kernel calls by reference ?

Comment: That is not possible (technically) :) But you the copy constructor was the way to go.